# What is 'free algebra'?

Tags: definition, free-groups

I've been googling the definition of it, and it seems like somehow it's related to a polynomial ring.

But I still quite don't get it.

Is a free algebra just a free group with additional operation (which is multiplication)?

Can anyone give me a simple explanation of it or any reference to it?

Thanks.

Comment: In my understanding, it is an algebra without any relations. You will not have, e.g., $a^2=a$ , etc. for some $a$ in the algebra.

Comment: Be careful about saying "free group."  In an algebra there is no division, so "free monoid" would be better to say.  If you are familiar with the group algebra, then, for metaphor, imagine the group algebra for a free group.  But then instead of a free group, use a free monoid of your basis elements to construct the free algebra.  It's like a polynomial ring, but not commutative (when the basis has more than one element): for basis elements $a,b$, you will not have $ab=ba$.

Comment: Thanks :) It's much clear now.

Comment: @gary, you **will** have that $1^2=1$ in any algebra, including free ones.

Comment: A "free algebra" is essentially a polynomial ring where any two different variables do not commute. So $xy$ is not equal to $yx$, $xyzz$ is not equal to $zyzx$, etc.   Essentially, other than the multiplicative associative property (and possibly identity) properties for rings, you have no other means of simplifying a product.

Comment: For example, $(a + b)(a + b) = a^2 + ab + ba + b^2$

Answer (score 5):

A free (associative) algebra is the non commutative analogue of the (associative) algebra of polynomials over a ring. If we have a ring $R$ we can get the polynomials over this ring in $R[X_1, X_2, \cdots,X_n]$. These polynomials have $n$ letters. Each term in a polynomial element could be thought of as a list of elements with their powers and some unit: $aX_1^{p_1}X_2^{p_2}\cdots X_n^{p_n}$. Ultimately the point is that order does not matter.

For a free algebra, the idea is to do the same but now we take care with order. Thus we have an algebra over some ring $R$ whose basis is all $n$ letter words. A typical element may look like this: $X_1X_3^2X_2$.

It could almost be thought of as the polynomial algebra is the free algebra modulo some commutator relation. The point is to not be able to change the order of multiplication as you could before.